# How to include an action link into a button's label?

Tags: r, shiny

My goal is to include an action link (that displays a help text) into the label of a `selectInput` button.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "some_id", 
    label = "Please choose A or B (get help)",
    choices = c("choice A", "choice B"),
    selected = "choice A",
    selectize = F
  ),
  actionLink(inputId = "action_link", label = "get help")
) # fluidPage

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I guess the solution is to use `label = HTML(...)`, but I do not know how to rewrite the action link in plain html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  selectInput(
    inputId = "some_id", 
    label = HTML("Please choose A or B", 
                 as.character(actionLink(inputId = 'action_link', label = 'get help'))),
    choices = c("choice A", "choice B"),
    selected = "choice A",
    selectize = F
  )
```

Comment: how would you do this while using `updateSelectInput`, I tried using the same `HTML` block, but it just prints the `HTML` code and not the intended `actionLink`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `tags` such as `a` and `p`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "some_id", 
    label = p("Please choose A or B ",a("get help", href = "https://www.google.com/", target = "_blank")),
    choices = c("choice A", "choice B"),
    selected = "choice A",
    selectize = F
  )
) # fluidPage

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This approach was new to me.